# Grouping a list of tuple which has two lists based on the second list

Tags: python, list, group-by

I have a sequence is like this,

`seq = [[["A","AA","AB"],[0,1,2,3]], [["B","BB","BC"],[1,2,3]], [["C","CA","CB"],[0,1,2,3]]]`

I wanted to convert this to something like below

`[[['A', 'AA', 'AB', 'C', 'CA', 'CB'], [0, 1, 2, 3]], [['B', 'BB', 'BC'], [1, 2, 3]]]`

I tried but I am getting like below. Can someone help in achieving the correct results.

```
In [105]: from itertools import groupby  
     ...: from operator import itemgetter  
     ...: seq = [[["A","AA","AB"],[0,1,2,3]], [["B","BB","BC"],[1,2,3]], [["C","CA","CB"],[0,1,2,3]]]  
     ...: seq.sort(key = itemgetter(1))  
     ...: groups = groupby(seq, itemgetter(1))  
     ...: [[(item[0],key) for item in data] for (key, data) in groups]                                                                                                                                                                
Out[105]: 
[[(['A', 'AA', 'AB'], [0, 1, 2, 3]), (['C', 'CA', 'CB'], [0, 1, 2, 3])],
 [(['B', 'BB', 'BC'], [1, 2, 3])]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
In [105]: from itertools import groupby  
     ...: from operator import itemgetter  
     ...: seq = [[["A","AA","AB"],[0,1,2,3]], [["B","BB","BC"],[1,2,3]], [["C","CA","CB"],[0,1,2,3]]]  
     ...: seq.sort(key = itemgetter(1))  
     ...: groups = groupby(seq, itemgetter(1))  
     ...: l = [[(item[0],key) for item in data] for (key, data) in groups] 
     ...: for i in l: 
     ...:     flat_list = [item for sublist in i[0] for item in sublist] 
     ...:     i[0] = flat_list
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the second list to tuple, use it as key in dictionary, to add first list's element in a set and sort it.

If there is duplicated element in the first list, you can change `set` to `list`, and `|=` to `.extend(x[0])`

```py
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(set)
>>> for x in seq:
       d[tuple(x[-1])] |= set(x[0])
>>> res = [[sorted(list(d[k])), list(k)] for k in d]
>>> res
[[['A', 'AA', 'AB', 'C', 'CA', 'CB'], [0, 1, 2, 3]], [['B', 'BB', 'BC'], [1, 2, 3]]]
```